# AMPPS - The file /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/includes/enduser.php is corrupted

Tags: apache, ampps

I've had this issue twice now, just randomly happened.

When I try to view the Ammps 'Home' Dashboard I get the following error:-

> The file /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/includes/enduser.php is
>   corrupted.

I had to re-install to fix this last time but since then (a few days ago) this has happened again?

Anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it?

I am using Version: 3.8

**Update**

I've done another clean install (backed up www and all the databases beforehand). I noticed there isn't even the directory `/Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/includes/`.

Seems to be another effected file as well:

> /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/includes/main/functions.php is
>   corrupted.

Upon opening these files, it appears a massively long string of characters as been added after the closing PHP tag. Deleting this string had no effect, the same errors persist.

Anyway, I've uploaded the files of Ampps for Mac which you can download here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18nA-ldR5BamLLqnEU0nC4Gx-PmzWSwt0/view?usp=sharing

Going to see if I can get it back working once I merge the files together (except the www folder)

**Update 2:**

You can now download Ampps 3.9 from their official website:

https://ampps.com/download

Comment: This worked for me!

I downloaded the AMPPS files for Mac you kindly provided. Then I replaced the existing Softaclous folder with the one from the download. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear that worked for you!

Comment: This issue is infuriating. I've already reinstalled 3.8 THREE TIMES. I know that I can still run my sites and use it while the backend is corrupted, but it's frustrating.

Comment: Seems they have released Ampps 3.9 now

Comment: Ooooooo. I hope that fixes this. Thanks!

Comment: So, it turns out 3.9 was only released for Windows. Hopefully they release it for Mac soon.

Comment: That's true on their official site, I'm on Mac and it got automatically upgraded to 3.9 though

Comment: @nsilva I'm on a mac as well, and mine didn't automatically update. But then mine has been having the problem in this thread, so maybe that has something to do with it?

The site has finally added the installer for 3.9 so I'm going to update it manually, and hope that this issue is fixed.

Comment: For anyone who comes here wanting to update Mac AMPPS from 3.8 to 3.9 manually because you've had this issue, and the app itself isn't auto updating for some reason, copying over your /var database directory does NOT work. Always keep backups. Don't just write over anything.

On that note: stuck on 3.8 for now. If anyone knows how to correctly do a manual update from 3.8 to 3.9, advice is greatly appreciated as I can't find anything on it atm.

Comment: You can download Ampps 3.9 here now: https://ampps.com/download

Answer (score 2):

Doing a clean install of Ampps 3.8 will rectify the problem which is what I had to do. Frustratingly, some people including myself have experienced the issue coming back after a few days. Until there is a permanent fix for this either by an update/patch from Softaculous, a way to rectify this without having to reinstall Ampps is by doing the following:-

1. Take a backup of your `/Applications/AMPPS/www` directory
2. Download the Mac files from a clean installation here;
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/18nA-ldR5BamLLqnEU0nC4Gx-PmzWSwt0/view?usp=sharing
3. Replace the existing Ampps directory with the files from the
   download link
4. Move your `/www/` folder back to the same location

You should then be able to access the Home dashboard and everything should work as normal.

**As Nika mentioned, don't forget to save database (/var) and domains information (/ampps/data/domains) before replacing files (/www)**

**Edit 1:**

Seems my version of Ampps 3.8 got updated to 3.9, I've not had any issues since this has happened.

Answer (score 2):

1.+ don't forget to save database (/var) and domains information (/ampps/data/domains) before replacing files

Answer (score 0):

Please create a backup first!

Shutdown AMPPS. I have fixed mine locally by replacing the enduser.php with the one from here https://files.ampps.com/5.3.2.zip.

Then after that I have replaced all the IonCube loaders with the ones you can download from here: https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php. Source and how-to: https://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=13497&title=Ioncube_Loader_Error

Start AMPPS.

To check if you need to replace another corrupt file check error_log in your logs folder.